# Why does my calculator function not return the correct result?

Tags: c, arithmetic-expressions

I am new to the C programming language. I am creating a simple calculator program, but my function for some reason isn't returning the right result. Here's my program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <complex.h>
#include <string.h>


int calculator(int x, char operator, int y);
int main()
{
    int x;
    char operator;
    int y;

    printf("Enter an arithmetic experession: ");
    scanf("%d%s%d", &x, &operator, &y);

    int result = calculator(x, operator, y);

    if(result == -1)
    {
        printf("Error! Try again!");
    }
    else
    {

        printf("%d", result);
    }
    return 0;


}
int calculator(int x, char operator, int y)
{
    int result = 0;
    if(y = 0)
    {
        return -1;
    }

    if(operator == '+')
    {
        result = x + y;
    }
    else if(operator == '-')
    {
        result = x - y;
    }
    else if(operator == '*')
    {
        result = x * y;
    }
    else if(operator == '/')
    {
        result = x / y;
    }
    else if(operator == '%')
    {
        result = x % y;
    }
    else
    {
        return -1;
    }

    return result;


}
```

So when I run this program it asks for an arithmetic expression. If I put in 5 + 3, it only returns 5! After a few tests it seems as though it only returns the first operand no matter what. I imagine it's something very minor, but I don't see what I'm missing.

Comment: C does not support _methods_, only _functions_. If you do not know the difference don't use the term.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two problems.  The first is where you're reading in the expression:

```
scanf("%d%s%d", &x, &operator, &y);
```

`operator` is a `char` but you're using the `%s` format specifier which is for a string.  This ends up putting the operator in `operator`, but then a NULL terminator is added to the next byte in memory.  Since this byte is not part of `operator`, this causes undefined behavior.

You want to use `%c` instead to read a single character.

The second is where you're doing the zero check on `y`:

```
if(y = 0)
```

This is an assignment, not a comparison.  The value `0` is assigned to `y`, then `y` is evaluated as a boolean, which ends up being false.  This is why all of your expressions evaluate as if `y` is 0.

Change this to an assignment:

```
if(y == 0)
```

Comment: Thanks, but now it is printing "Error! Try again!" which means calculator for some reason is returning -1, which it should only do if y is 0.

Comment: @user2817803 you input `5+3` or `%d %c %d` instead of `%d%c%d`

Comment: @BLUEPIXY ok so I changed it to `%d %c %d` and it worked! Thanks